# output Tree from string input

Tags: javascript, string

I need to solve a problem but i don't know how !
With JS i get a string input like :

```
`#Animal>
#Reptile>
#lizard;
#crocodile;
\\;
#Feline>
#Tiger;
#Cat;
#Leopard;
\\;
\\;
.`
```

With this rules :

'#'  => line start

';' => end of line

'>' => branch Start

'\' => end of branch

'.' => end of string

And the output will be ( with tab and sorted branches ) :

```
Animal
  Feline
     Cat
     Leopard
     Tiger
  Reptile
     crocodile
     lizard
```

I can make the tree with this but i don't know how to sort branches.

```
const transformText = (text)=>{
  const enter =  "\n" ;
  const tab = "\t";
  const special =  ['#', ';','>','\\','.'];
  let nbTab = 0;
  result = '';
 
  text.forEach(bloc => {
      [...bloc].forEach((caracter)=>{
              if(special.includes(caracter)){
                  switch(caracter){
                      case '#': break;
                      case ';': result += enter + tab.repeat(nbTab); 
                      break;
                      case '>' : nbTab++ ; result += enter + tab.repeat(nbTab);
                      break;
                      case '\\' : nbTab--;
                      break;
                      case('.') : break;
                  }
              }else{
                  result += caracter;
                  // console.log(result);
              }
          })
  });
  return result.normalize();

}
```

Comment: You can't easily do any "sorting" in a string value, and especially not while you are still in the process of assembling that string value. You should put this data into an array structure first, then sort what needs sorting in there, and then only after that transform the structure into the string output format you desire.

Comment: Thanks . And if i want sort this structure by branch , how can i proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 rules in your string

```
#section> 
#childItem;
\\;
.
```

You could create a regex to match them and process them one by one.

```
([#\\.])([^>;]*)([>;])*
```

You can see the matches and explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/Rz5kUB/1

Then loop through each match and process them. Create a `root` object and keep a variable `current` to keep track of your current section. In every section add a `parent` property to help you go back up the chain when you get a `\\;`.

```js
let input =
  `#Animal>
#Reptile>
#lizard;
#crocodile;
\\;
#Feline>
#Tiger;
#Cat;
#Leopard;
\\;
\\;
.`

let regex = /([#\\.])([^>;]*)([>;]*)/g,
    matches = Array.from(input.matchAll(regex)),
    root = { children: [] },
    current = root

for (const [match, start, text, end] of matches) {
  if (end === '>') {
    const section = { text, children: [], parent: current }
    current.children.push(section) // add the child section
    current = section // go down to nested section
  } 
  else if (start == "\\") {
    current.children?.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text))
    current = current.parent // go back up to parent section
  } 
  else if (end === ";")
    current.children.push({ text })
  else if (start === '.')
    break;
}

// removing the parent property from JSON to avoid circular structure
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(root.children, (k, v) => k === 'parent' ? undefined : v, 2)
)
```